# Linear Independence or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is  {$\cos (x), \sin (x), \cos (2x) $} linearly independent?

I did: $a\cos (x)+b \sin (x)+c \cos (2x)=0$

When $x=0\implies a=-c$

When $x=\frac\pi2\implies b=c$

When $x=\frac\pi4\implies a=-b$

Therefore, $-c\cos (x)+c \sin (x)+c \cos (2x)=0$

$c(-\cos (x)+ \sin (x)+ \cos (2x))=0$

$\cos(x)=\sin (x)+ \cos (2x)\implies$ Linear Dependence

I know this is wrong but where is my mistake?

Comment: You didn't check that $c \neq 0$, so you can't conclude that $\cos(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(2x)$ from the previous line. Try plugging $x = \pi$ into $a \cos(x) + b \sin(x) + c \cos(2x) = 0$ to find another relation among the coefficients $a,b,c$.

Comment: A set of functions $\{f_{1}, f_{2}, \dots, f_{n}\}$ is linearly dependent over the real numbers if there exist real constants $c_{1}, \dots, c_{n}$, not all zero, such that $c_{1} f_{1}(x) + \dots + c_{n} f_{n}(x) = 0$ for all real numbers $x$. Note that $c(-\cos(x) + \sin(x) + \cos(2x)) \neq 0$ for $x = \pi$ unless $c=0$, in which case this still doesn't show linear dependence because all the coefficients are zero.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: what you did is fine, put another value $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$ into the equation, and together with the relation you found: $b = -a, c = -a \to a = b = c = 0$ , they are linearly independent.

Comment: The identity a cos(x) + b sin(x) + c cos(2x) = 0 must hold for every x. How one can give particular values of x and how to be sure there are no other values of a,b,c satisfying the given identity.